# Error Using @emotion/core in my React app

Tags: reactjs, emotion

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL9Sp.png)  Please help, these errors are preventing my react app from compiling. How do I fix it?
I also attached a picture of the App.tsx file
What is another suggestion for taking care of this error?

Could not find a declaration file for module '@emotion/core'. 'c:/Users/nwoko/source/repos/QandA/QandAfrontend/frontend/node_modules/@emotion/core/dist/emotion-core.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/emotion__core` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@emotion/core';`ts(7016)

Type '{ children: Element[]; css: any; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'.
Property 'css' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>'.ts(2322)

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlF0z.png)

Comment: You are running your all through typescript? It is asking you to also install the types for the emotion library. Type npm install --save-dev @types/emotion

Comment: @Faktor10, yes, I am running typescript the command you suggested did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Capitalizing on @sanderdebr suggestion,

I ran `npm install --save @emotion/react` before changing the import line to `import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react'` and got rid of TypeScript error TS7016

I then added `"types": ["@emotion/react/types/css-prop"]` in file tsconfig.json to get rid of the second ts error (2322)

Answer (score 5):

Helped me:

tsconfig.json

```
"types": ["@emotion/react/types/css-prop"],
```

*.tsx

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic */
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx, css } from "@emotion/react";
```

Answer (score 2):

use  `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */` instead `/** @jsx jsx */`

Comment: Suggestion to improve this post: You could provide insight on rationale behind.

Answer (score 1):

Emotion is suggesting to use @emotion/react in their docs. Try to install use emotion for React with command `npm install --save @emotion/react` and then `import { jsx, css } from '@emotion/react'`

Comment: importing from '@emotion/core' does not compile. importing from '@emotion/react' does. But still, I get the same error as @KingNOB : 
 Property 'css' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.  TS2322

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic /
/* @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "@emotion/react";
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new version MUI you need to install the following two packages:

```
npm install --save @emotion/react
npm install --save @emotion/styled
```